# C# generating lake-like shapes in a 2d top-down tile grid

Tags: c#, game-development, topdown

I'm a beginner in game development and want to create a top-down game using tilemaps. I'm using Godot as my game engine but a general C# solution is fine.

I'm looking to generate lakes in the tilemap but I can't come up with any ideas that might work due to my inexperience. Previously I tried using Simplex, but I decided against it due to the lack of control over where the lakes spawn.

Performance is somewhat important but the world will be finite and not procedural, similar to Terraria.

I'm open to any ideas on the matter that would be reasonable within a videogame.

Comment: This question seem way to broad. I would recommend focusing on a specific problem, and describe the actual problem, what approach(es) you have attempted, and the problems you have encountered.

Comment: @JonasH The only problem I have is that I don't have enough experience with graphics to know where to begin with something like this. What I have attempted is stated in the question: Simplex noise.

Comment: So, what research have you done? what have you implemented so far? What result did you get? what result did you expect? "more control over where lakes are placed" - Why would you expect *any* control, noise is by random. Are you asking about how to implement simplex noise, or how to use it to get the result you want?

Comment: @JonasH I've looked for tutorials on world generation. I had Simplex noise but I scrapped it. I got a lot of random bits of water tiles. I didn't expect any control, I decided I wanted control when Simplex noise was too random. I'm asking for any way to create passable lake-like shapes in a tilemap, this may use Simplex but I want to have control over it so I figured it won't be the best option.

Comment: Can you show us what results you got with your simplex approach?

Comment: @Akade I clarified in the post that I'm not looking to continue with Simplex :)

Comment: Not sure if it is of any use, but here's a [shape generator](https://rowan-mulder.github.io/Shape-Generator) built with javascript and SVG. This isn't aimed to be a straight implementation, but to show a simple solution while maintaining utmost control. You could take a look here at the [repository](https://github.com/Rowan-Mulder/Shape-Generator) to see how it's implemented. I'm sure there are plenty of better ways the same result can be achieved, but for beginning programmers perhaps a simple solution may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a finite world size, I can sketch an approach for you that you can try out. It is not language specific but you should be able to do that (easily) with C#:

- The tiled world is represented as a bitmap: 0=land, 1=water
- To generate a lake, mark the starting tile as water and add its coordinates to a queue
- Deque a point from the queue. For that tile and for each direction, randomly decide if that adjacent tile is also water. Add newly added tiles to the queue.

  - Control the lake shape by different probabilities for different directions
  - Control the size of the lake by either limiting the iteration count or by decreasing the chance of a new water tile by the distance from the starting point
- Repeat until the queue is empty.

Let me know how this workes out - I have only tested it using my mental code simulator so mileage may vary;) If you need help in implementing that approach, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I tried something similar but without using different probabilities for directions, resulting in a diamond shaped lake... I'll keep this in mind though! Thanks!